# Избежание IndexOutOfBoundsException в Geocoder

Tags: java, android, массивы, исключения

Имеется следующий код для получения названия города через Geocoder.

```
  Locale locale =  Locale.getDefault(); 
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, locale);
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 5);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                if (city == null) {
                   city = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                }
```

Но в некоторых местах, например, в Барнауле выкидывает вот это. Как с этим бороться?

```
2020-08-30 11:32:04.794 9011-9011/com.example.cleanzy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cleanzy, PID: 9011
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.cleanzy.MainActivity$DownloadJSONTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:119)
        at com.example.cleanzy.MainActivity$DownloadJSONTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: Geocoder - порой может вернуть null на некоторых устройствах, т.е. функционал теряться будет. Мое дело лишь предупредить)

Comment: есть какой-то аналог geocoder'у ? Желательно без таких явлений

Comment: конечно, retrofit + json https://tech.yandex.com/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples-docpage/ - лучше яндекс, больше халявы в запросах, гугл лесом

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Может как ответ оформите, чтобы принять можно было?

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте проверку

```
if (addresses.size() > 0) {
    city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    if (city == null) {
      city = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    }
}
```